# using selenium.type() method in c# raising error a.CreateEventObject is not a function

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium for testing, while entering text in textbox by its Id, some time it raises a error !

Error Message: An unhandled exception of type System.InvalidOperationExecution occured in webdriver.dll.
Additional information : a.CreateEventObject is not a function (Unexpected Java Script Error)

I have checked things like if the textbox with id present and Used Selenium.sendkeys and its working... but dont know why selenium.type() fails sometime.

```
selenium.Type(locator,value);
```

Comment: dont know why negetive voting, if this is easy one then please provide the answer...

Answer (score 0):

`selenium.Type(locator,value);` is using **Selenium-RC** API. If you want to use **Selenium-WebDriver** API, you will need to use `WebDriver.findElement().sendKeys()`.

Note that in Selenium 2, both APIs are available, even though RC is now deprecated. In Selenium 3, RC will be completely removed.

Comment: The answer is: Selenium-RC has been deprecated for several years now, and is no longer stable. Stop using it!

Comment: i also dont want to use it but having some problem with sendkeys(). Javascript on page dont catch the textbox value when using sendkeys()

Comment: This sounds a like a new problem now.